# mysql как сделать выборку по двум разным годам

Tags: sql

Есть таблица **invoice**, в ней есть колонка **InvoiceDate**, нужно сделать выборку за 2009 и 2011 года (не в период с 2009 по 2011, отдельно), и посчитать количество строк за каждый год. Так же в таблице invoice есть колонка **Total** (type: float), нужно посчитать сколько в сумме объем продаж за эти года. **Буду очень благодарен за помощь!!!**
[image]

Вот так получилось у меня, но получилось только за один год. Но я так понимаю что через View такое не сделаешь. Должно получиться 3 колонки:

1. Дата (2009,2011)
2. Количество строк за этот год.
3. Общая сумма за этот год.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(InvoiceDate) IN (2009, 2011)`

Comment: Выводит как одну строку и считает как интервал с 2009 по 2011

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_invoices AS
  
SELECT year(InvoiceDate), count(InvoiceDate), sum(Total)
  
FROM invoice
  
WHERE year(InvoiceDate) in (2009,2011)
  
group by year(InvoiceDate)
```

Comment: если у вас много данных, то `year()` исключит использование индекса и будет полное чтение таблицы